# Miniature Peperomia Pilea depressa, losing leaves and color

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-health, indoors, growth

I've had this plant for about 9monthes and it's been generally doing well, it even sprouted new babies (?).
However, in the last 3 months, a good amount of its leaves are browsing and falling off. I don't have it in direct sunlight, and I water it about 1 a week.
Any suggestions on how to keep it alive? This is a Mini-Peperomia
Pilea depressa.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This plant does not like dry air, draughts, or changes in temperature, and is often used in bottle gardens or terrariums because of its liking for unchanging conditions and humidity.

You haven't said where you are, but if you're somewhere  it gets cold from autumn, I imagine you've got your heating on, and will have had for a while. If that's the case, it won't like that  much, and it definitely won't like the change in temperature overnight when the heating is switched off. If you can find a spot out of draughts, increase the  humidity around it, nowhere near any heating devices or anything that gives off heat, that might mean it does better. It will also do better if its grouped with other plants, so they can create a bit of a micro-environment for it - or try standing it on a pebble tray much bigger than the pot, half filled with water, not so that the bottom of the pot  is in the water, but so that the water evaporates around  the plant to raise the humidity. It doesn't like to run short of water, but doesn't need so much during winter, as growth slows because of lower daylight levels.

All that said, I'm sorry to say the only one of these I managed to keep going for any length of time was the one I planted in a bottle garden...